# Spark: printing Hbase data and converting it into Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-spark-sql

I am having difficulty in playing with the data received from my Hbase table. I have a Hbase table `EMP_META: COLUMN_NAME,SALARY,DESIGNATION,BONUS` and I read it using below code:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val sc = new SparkContext("local", "hbase-test")
println("Running Phoenix Context")
val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, "EMP_META")
val hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat], classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[Result])
println("--------------: "+hBaseRDD.first())
}
```

However when I print it using the above print statement I get below output:

```
(65 6d 70 6c 6f 79 65 65,keyvalues={employee/0:COLUMN_NAME/1483975443911/Put/vlen=4/seqid=0, employee/0:DATA_TYPE/1483975443911/Put/vlen=7/seqid=0, employee/0:_0/1483975443911/Put/vlen=1/seqid=0})
```

Instead of simple data text row. I want to convert the output to a dataframe so that I can easily play with the data. Can someone please help me in this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert hbaseRDD to DataFrame,you can use the follow code:

```
  val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
  import sqlContext.implicits._
  hBaseRDD.toDF
```

If you want to convert the result to String, you should convert the Array[Byte] to String.The data stored in HBase is Array[Byte].Try to use Bytes.toString(data) to convert it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I was doing some senseless stuff, I have one more question. How can I get the list of all the columns in output? With the method `getRow()` I can get the key column and `value` gives the 2nd column but I am not able to get rest of the columns.

Comment: The value should be the row in the hbase,you can get each column.May be you code has set the column,otherwise,all of columns you can get.